# Azure PowerShell Invoke-Sqlcmd : Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

I have a SQL Server stored procedure which accepts first two parameters as `uniqueidentifier` and a third as `nvarchar`. When I execute against Azure SQL database in SSMS, it works fine and no problem but when I use Azure PowerShell, then I get the following exception

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier.

PowerShell script

```
 $parameter1 = New-Guid
 $parameter2 = New-Guid
 $parameter3 = "Test"

 $DatabaseName = "xxxx"
 $ServerName = "xxxx"

 $sqlQuery = "
            EXEC [dbo].[spxxxxxx]
            @parameter1 = [Guid]${parameter1},
            @parameter2 = [Guid]${parameter2},
            @parameter3 = '${parameter3}'
          "
 $params = @{
          'Database' = $DatabaseName
          'ServerInstance' = $ServerName
          'Username' = 'xxxx'
          'Password' = 'xxxx'
          'OutputSqlErrors' = $true
          'Query' =  $sqlQuery
    }

Invoke-Sqlcmd @params
```

Can anyone suggest how do I pass `Guid` `parameters` for stored procedure in PowerShell using `Invoke-Sqlcmd` to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always when constructing SQL queries, print them out and examine them.  You're generating somethign like:

```
    EXEC [dbo].[spxxxxxx]
    @parameter1 = [Guid]2e244a72-1e11-496d-8a7f-37844ae8ce6b,
    @parameter2 = [Guid]5fe0e88f-9bea-4a9f-b67e-fe55cdcadfbc,
    @parameter3 = 'Test'
```

but the batch should look like

```
    EXEC [dbo].[spxxxxxx]
    @parameter1 =  '2e244a72-1e11-496d-8a7f-37844ae8ce6b',
    @parameter2 =  '5fe0e88f-9bea-4a9f-b67e-fe55cdcadfbc',
    @parameter3 = 'Test'
```

when passing a string literal that will be implicitly converted to a UNQUEIDENTIFIER.

Comment: Thank you very much for the print tip and solution. it worked!